# 'Find' output as the range of 'for' in Bash is doing in batch mode

Tags: linux, bash, find

I did a loop process using Bash `for` command, on Linux mint, with the input range is from previous process comes from `find`, but it'd apparently and clearly did it in batch process relative to terminal output, rather than the immediate one if `find` range is explicit and performed to give a terminal output.
mine is;

```
IFS=$'\n'
for s in $(find ~+ -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex ".*/data\.(tmp|bak)" -printf '%p\n')
    {
    echo $s
    }
```

it'll be still without any output for 100 sec. or more, rather than straightly shows some on terminal.
How to make it work as nearly fast as `find` instructed alone and directly ? thanks inadvance, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop iterates over a *static* list, always.  So the body of the loop in your question will not start executing until the items that it will iterate over are completely specified.  These will not be completely specified until the `find` command has finished executing.

There are several issues with your command, and most are addressed by the question "[Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)".

In general, it's better to have `find` act as a pathname generator for an internal script:

```
find ~+ -type f \( -iname data.tmp -o -iname data.bak \) -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # process "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

This way, you don't need to care about how the pathnames that `find` gives to the loop are delimited (this will gracefully handle pathnames containing spaces and newlines etc.)

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: `-exec ... {} +` will still of course batch, but it might depend on the implementation _how much_ it does. On Linux, GNU find seems to batch up to a command line length of 128 kB, even though the actual limit is higher.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, it will batch, and the original command in the question (if the syntax was corrected) would not batch but wait until the full command had finished.